# UITableView and NSMutableArray dynamic?

Tags: iphone, ios5, tableview

I have a tableview where the user can add a cell (with textfield in it) by pressing an add button.

I write the text (from textfield) to NSMutable array, and save in NSUserdefaults. works fine!

But when the user selects (for example) row 5, I switch to a new view with some textfields in it.

How can I add the values (text) from the textfields in a new array and store it in the userdefaults? Should I create an array for each row the user has selected? (indexpath.row) I need the values to show in another view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSMutableDictionary. It would look like:

```
{
    "rowOne":{"textFieldOne":"DataOne", "textFieldTwo":"DataTwo"},
    "rowTwo":{"textFieldOne":"DataOne", "textFieldTwo":"DataTwo"}
}
```

To get out your Array of the tableViewCells like you were before you would use:
tableArray = [dictFromUserDefaults allKeys];

When you need to get the data for the fields with in that row you use

```
dataDictionary = [dictFromUserDefaults objectForKey:[tableArray objectAtIndex:index.row]];
```

And for each textField you would use:

```
textfieldOne.text = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"textFieldOne"];
```

Comment: ..i have to think about- i have to use the mutabledictionray in the class with my 2 textfields. but where is connection from the selected row in revious (table)view? i don´t know how many rows are added from the user

Comment: Well you need to connect the selected row in the tableView to the Data the textfield data.